# primefaces dropdowns not working with ajax JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a big problem with selectOnMenu in JSF2, i tried to use this component with  but not working , i tested also the primefaces example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml but without any new result .

i think that i miss some config or filter about ajax in my project or my page.

*Here is dropdown code*:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width:300px;"  value="#{parameterBean.name}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select parameter Type" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{parameterTypeBean.listParameterTypes}"  var="ptype"     itemValue="#{ptype.id}" itemLabel="#{ptype.name}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{parameterBean.serviceChange}" event="change" update="pTable" process="@form"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

*This is my simple actionBean* :

```
    public void serviceChange() {
    System.out.println("change");
}
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Wrong method signature

Comment: See 11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked Having no argument is wrong as well

Answer (score -1):

remove process="@form" so it would be

```
<p:ajax listener="#{parameterBean.serviceChange}" event="change" update="pTable"/>
```

Comment: That is the default so leaving it out does not make a difference (at least it should not) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces

Comment: But most likely with a different signature of the service method.